# function is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

I am having trouble reloading the page. I tried to use JavaScript in Vue by adding this code

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
   window.location.reload()
}
```

This error is poppng up:

```
 74:10  error  'myFunction' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see your function enclosed inside script tag

Comment: yes I have included my function in script tag

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
              window.location.reload()

}

</script>

Comment: Add `"no-unused-vars": "off"` in the `"rules"` of `"eslintConfig"` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 5):

`no-unused-vars` is a ESLint warning. It occurs because you don't call your function anywhere in your javascript code, and ESLint cannot read that it is being called from an HTML attribute.

You can turn off this warning like this:

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
function myFunction() {
  window.location.reload()
}
/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
</script>
```

---

Although calling javascript functions from HTML attributes is not good practice today.

There is a javascript way to wait for the load event, instead of using `onload` attribute:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.reload()
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction);
</script>
```

---

Regarding the comment on the page reload only once. You can keep the fact that the page has been reloaded in the `localStorage`:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Check that the page has not been reloaded
  if (localStorage.getItem('reloaded') === null) {
    // Save the fact that we are reloading the page, and reload page
    localStorage.setItem('reloaded', true);
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, reset the flag so that on the fresh load the page can be reloaded again
    localStorage.removeItem('reloaded');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: nina it keeps on refreshing my browser with infinite

Comment: I just want to refresh once

Comment: @JeremyWarren Yeah, that's what your code does, it reloads the page after it's loaded. You have to add some kind of condition to `window.location.reload()` call. Under what exactly conditions do you want to reload the page?

Comment: the thing is that i want to refresh my browser only once and display the data not always refreshing without non stop

Comment: To reload page once, you should somehow preserve the fact that the page has been reloaded, outside of the page state, to avoid reloading it again, so you can use `localStorage`, url request variables or something similar to do this.

Comment: @JeremyWarren I have added an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

please use script tag for function or any javascript related code.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'>
     function myFunction() {
          window.location.reload()
     }
</script>
```